# Installing failes for plugin “atom-typescript@8.5.0” in github's atom ide

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I am trying to install [atom-typescript](https://atom.io/packages/atom-typescript) package in GitHub's Atom.  When I press the `Install` button I get the following error.

```
Installing atom-typescript to C:\Users\vadherak\.atom\packages
assert.js:93
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: Expected there to only be one child in node_modules
    at C:\Users\vadherak\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.7.0-beta1\resources\app\apm\lib\install.js:165:22
    at ChildProcess.onChildExit (C:\Users\vadherak\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.7.0-beta1\resources\app\apm\lib\command.js:51:49)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

I have tried installing using command prompt too, it is giving me same error.

Finally, I tried executing the
`apm install --check` command and it showed `Checking for native build tools done`, regardless of executing this command I got the same error when I tried to install the package.

If have logged this issues as [an issue with the atom-typescript](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/909) project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alluded to in my comment on your GitHub Issue for this problem, can I ask you to either update to `1.7.0-beta4` and try to install `atom-typescript` again, if it is still a problem for you please can you post a full list of the packages you have installed.

You can get a list of all installed packages from the command line by issuing the following command:

```
 apm list
```

This will print a list of all of the packages installed both built-in and community:

```
Built-in Atom Packages (89)
├── about@1.4.2
├── archive-view@0.61.1
├── atom-dark-syntax@0.27.0
├── atom-dark-ui@0.51.0
├── atom-light-syntax@0.28.0
...

Community Packages (49) C:\Users\richa\.atom\packages
├── apm-publish@0.3.0
├── atom-dns-resolver@1.3.0
├── atom-html-preview@0.1.19
├── atom-shortcuts@0.0.2
├── atom-svg-icon-snippets@0.2.0
├── atom-ternjs@0.13.2
....
```

This is extremely helpful to us in diagnosing issues with atom given nearly infinite possible combinations of packages and software versions.

Comment: I tried installing stable version and it is working now.

Comment: I haven't installed any packages. I installed beta version and it had only packages it shipped with. This was first plugin I was installing.